# Extracting several strings in a regexp

Tags: shell

I have a FILE consisting of lines like the following:

```
URL=http://someURL]somefilename
```

I need to download the URL link if somefilename isn't already there.
I wanted to use shell command like:

```
for i in $(cat FILE); do if [ ! -f somefilename] somecode; done
```

but I don't know what to use for somecode. Any ideas?

edit:
To address terdon questions:
Yes there is only one ] per line, the one after someURL
and yes the filename is the whole string after ] to the end of the line.

Comment: How can we know where the file name starts? Will it *always* be the string after `]`? Can there be multiple `]`s per line? Multiple URLs per line? Are you sure that's supposed to be a `]` and not a `?` or `&`? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pure shell approach:

```
while IFS='=]' read a url file; do 
    [ -f "$file" ] || echo "wget $url]$file"
done < file
```

This will iterate over the file, splitting each line on either `=` or `]` and reading each resulting fields into the variables a (the string `URL`), `$url` (the url until the file name) and `$file` (the file name). Then, if the `$file` doesn't exist in the current directory (so `[ -f "$file" ]` returns false), it will download it.